# Solve unit cross reference issue

Tags: delphi

i create a first unit with basic class definitions like

```
unit_classtype;
type 
TMyClass = class(..)
     .....
end;

end.
```

In a second unit I store a lot of helper functions for this first unit

```
unit_classtype_helper; 

uses  unit_classtype;

    procedure WriteMyClasstoStringlist (aStringlist : TStringlist; aClass : TMyClass);


implementation

    procedure WriteMyClasstoStringlist (aStringlist : TStringlist; aClass : TMyClass);
begin
   aStringlist.add ('info on my Class', MyClass.Data );
   ....
end;
```

Now I want to build a MycLass.savetoFile function and use the code from WriteMyClasstoStringlist, but I can not include the helpunit in the class definition unit because of the cross reference.

Shifting the code is no option, I need some other solution

Comment: Writing good quality maintainable code is ***fundamentally*** about putting code in the "right" place - _where it belongs_. Yet you say that is not an option? What "knows best" about what is going on inside `TMyClass` and what should be written to the string list to **best** represent an instance? You can choose any of the following: `TMyClass`, `TMyClass` or `TMyClass`. ..... So, although you claim shifting the code is no option, the only ***correct*** option is to add `public procedure WriteToStrings(AStrings: TStrings);` to `TMyClass`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quess right now you're tring to include both units in the interface section, but you only need the `unit_classtype_helper` in the implementation of the `unit_classtype` so organise your code like this:

```
unit unit_classtype;

interface

type 
  TMyClass = class(..)
     .....
  end;

implementation

uses
  unit_classtype_helper;
...
end.
```